# Dell Inspiron 7370 eGPU via USB 3.1 with PCI-E USB riser card

Tags: laptop, usb, drivers, graphics-card, pci-express

I realize thunderbolt is far better for creating an effective eGPU. However, the laptop I have is a Dell Inspiron 7370 (http://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/dell-laptops/inspiron-13-7000/spd/inspiron-13-7370-laptop/dncwka001h). The computer lacks thunderbolt, but instead has USB 3.1 Gen 1 which, according to [this table](https://thunderbolttechnology.net/sites/default/files/more%20speed.jpg) supports throughput of 10GBps compared to 40GBps with thunderbolt 3.

Could I get a USB to PCIE card [like this](https://www.ebay.com/itm/PCI-E-Express-X1-to-Dual-PCI-Riser-Extend-Adapter-Card-Board-w-1m-USB3-0-Cable/162706785261?_trkparms=aid%3D555019%26algo%3DPL.BANDIT%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D20150817211758%26meid%3D5542ec43101e4997b4c17021081da487%26pid%3D100507%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D1%26%26itm%3D162706785261&_trksid=p2045573.c100507.m3226) to use a graphics card? I have a spare desktop power supply which could power the graphics card.

I don't expect excellent performance but I would get a GTX 750TI graphics card (about $40 on eBay) to match the performance limitations of USB 3.1.

As for driver support, wouldn't the computer recognize the card with the PCIE and then I could install drivers for the graphics card? I remember reading on another Super User post that USB 3 requires converting protocols twice though it may have applied to a different context.

Could someone explain why this might not work? What are the performance limitations? Would the performance boost surpass the Intel HD 6000 integrated chip I have now?

Thank you.

Comment: The product linked is not a "USB to PCIE card" but a PCI-E x1  to **dual PCI** (standard old PCI). It's not for modern graphics cards.

Comment: @MichaelBay Ah, I didn't realize. How about this (https://www.ebay.com/itm/Lot-BTC-Riser-Card-USB-3-0-PCI-E-Express-1x-To-16x-Extender-Adapter-Power-Cable/401348357952?hash=item5d7239ef40:m:msiP49TxTEGQsPDkKvfIV0w) one?

Comment: That adapter is for desktops only (the previous one the same actually). Both require a PCI-E x1 slot and the second one also additional power. Unfortunately, what you want doesn't exist: https://superuser.com/questions/1036568/external-graphics-card-on-a-dual-usb-3-0-laptop?rq=1

Comment: use Adapter that uses mPCIe (from Wifi module in the laptop): http://www.hwtools.net/Adapter/PE4C%20V3.0.html